# Upgrade PHP 5.6 to 7.2

Tags: php, rpm

I currently have php72 installed on amazon linux one.

```
[ehost ~]$ php -v
PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (    built: Oct 16     2018 23:50:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c)     1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

When I attempt to install a custom rpm     I get the following.

How do I let the rpm know that PHP 7.2 is already installed?

> Error: Package: mct_console-3.40.1- 
>       6624_f7150d48.noarch (/mct_console- 
>       3.40.1-6624_f7150d48.noarch)
>                  Requires: php >= 7.0.2
>                 Available: php-5.3.29- 
>       1.8.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)

Another Error:

> Error: Package: mct_console-3.40.1- 
>       6624_f7150d48.noarch (/mct_console- 
>       3.40.1-6624_f7150d48.noarch)
>              Requires: php-mysql >= 7.0.2
>              Available: php-mysql-5.3.29- 
>       1.8.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)

Comment: Might be better on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

The packages `php` and `php72` are two separate packages. You have one called `php` but it's only 5.3.29. If that's your only dependency that is missing, you can do `rpm -i --nodeps` to get around it.

However, whatever tool you are trying to install will need to have the `PATH` fixed in whatever you are currently doing it to change the default `php` executable to be the 7.2 one.